# C# dll hooks: passing null as parameter

Tags: c#, hook

I have successfully hooked a dll function in c#

```
[DllImport ("ftusbsrv.dll", EntryPoint="FtEnumDevices")]
public unsafe static extern bool FtEnumDevices(ref FT_SERVER_USB_DEVICE lpUsbDevices, ref ulong pulBufferSize, ref FT_ERROR_STATE lpES);
```

I need to pass null as as first parameter as below

```
FtEnumDevices(null, pulBufferSize,lpES);
```

I am getting the following compile time error:

> Argument '1': cannot convert from
>   '' to 'ref
>   FebulaTechWrapper.USBOverNetWrapper.FT_SERVER_USB_DEVICE'

I need to know: How can I pass null  as a first parameter?

Comment: It doesn't look like the first parameter is the problem...

Comment: sorry the error wasnt posted correct

Argument '1': cannot convert from '' to 'ref FebulaTechWrapper.USBOverNetWrapper.FT_SERVER_USB_DEVICE'

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that `null` is your problem - it seems like `lpEs` is an `int` in your code but `ftusbsrv.dll` is expecting a type of `FebulaTechWrapper.USBOverNetWrapper.FT_ERROR_STATE`.

You will need to recreate `FT_ERROR_STATE` in your C# code so that you can pass an instance to the method instead of an `int`.

**Edit:**  You cannot pass null to a method that expects a `ref` argument.  A `ref` argument needs a reference, try something like this:

```
FT_SERVER_USB_DEVICE dummy = null;

FtEnumDevices(ref dummy, pulBufferSize, lpES);
```

Comment: sorry the error wasnt posted correct Argument '1': cannot convert from '' to 'ref FebulaTechWrapper.USBOverNetWrapper.FT_SERVER_USB_DEVICE'